# How to copy the text from a Windows control which does not allow the text to be selected?

Tags: windows-10

I want to get the text from a stringgrid in a Windows program. The control does not allow the text to be selected.

To complicate matters, my company laptop is locked down and I cannot install any programs, not even MS Power Toys, so if it can't be done natively in windows, I will have to ask on https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ for a portable solution.

[Update} we have Windows 10 and the company will not budge on installing software. Also, the text would not be allowed to be sent to a remote server to perform OCR.  Further,the control has scroll bars and could have 1,000s of entires. I don't wan to make 100s of screenshots.

I guess that I will ask on https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: If you use Windows 11, you can create a screenshot using the snippet tool, and use that exact same tool to do text recognition.

Comment: If a screen capture (built in) does not work. then this appears to be a question for your company.

Comment: Sorry, we have only WIndwos 10 (I should ahve stated) and the company will not budge on installing software. I guess that I will ask on https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/  Also, the text would not be allowed to be sent to a remote server to perform OCR.  Further,the control has scroll bars and could have 1,000s of entires. I don't wan to make 100s of screenshots

Comment: If ocr'ing your screen is part of your job, and the company does not want to help, you could also ask at https://workplace.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You could try using the Google translate app on your phone to ocr your laptop. Or any other ocr app that runs on your phone for that matter